# Locking a formula when adding rows

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Currently I have this formula in there

```
=IF('Form Responses 3'!G$20="","",COUNTIF('Form Responses 3'!G$1:G$167,F20))
```

It does what I want it to do if I go in a tweak it later, but I don't want to go in a tweak it

Because it's a form responses tab, every time a new form is submitted it adds a new row in and my reference cell changes. I've done some research and tried out the INDIRECT function (`=IF(INDIRECT('Form Responses 3'!G$20)="","",COUNTIF('Form Responses 3'G$1:G$167,F20)`), but I can't seem to get the reference cell to stay G20.

My formula is on a different tab in cell C4.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Show how you tried to use indirect and tell us where are you adding you formula.

Comment: =IF(INDIRECT('Form Responses 3'!G$20)="","",COUNTIF('Form Responses 3'G$1:G$167,F20))

My formula is on a different tab in cell C4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in `=IF(INDIRECT('Form Responses 3'!G$20)="","",COUNTIF('Form Responses 3'G$1:G$167,F20))` is that INDIRECT requires a text value but you are passing a reference. To fix it enclose `'Form Responses 3'!G$20` between `"`.

Resulting formula:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("'Form Responses 3'!G$20")="","",COUNTIF('Form Responses 3'!G$1:G$167,F20))
```

Comment: It's saying Formula Parse Error

Comment: That is b/c the original formula has an error. It's missing the `!` in `'Form Responses 3'G$1:G$167`. Formula fixed in the answer.